# Images no shrink when resizing the site in responsive design

Tags: html, css

I have my site :
www.emantiss.com

And when Im resizing the site the main image on the top not resizing with the site it self.
Just when im doing a refresh to the page the new size get in action.
Im trying alot of things with max-width and this code:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

but it doesnt work for me.
If some1 can help me. it Will be great.

Comment: Firstly, please don't do this `maximum-scale=1.0` it's a poor user experience. Have you given your images fixed widths? Have you give images `max-width:100%;`

Comment: try `img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }` __edit__ just checked the site, you'll need to play around with it a bit, the script is applying widths and heights dynamically and overriding the CSS.

Comment: Further to the comment above `maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0` disables a users ability to pinch/zoom/scale your site on a touch enabled device.

Comment: I added this code after I've read some comments about the same problem here. But ok I remove this code but it still Doesnt work. Ive tried to fixed it so much time and I dont find solution. Please if some1 Can, It will be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want images to be sized according to the size of the browser window you have to use relative value, i.e. percentual values. You can use media queries in your css file to limit this behavior to windows not until a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

This is one quick way of doing it provided you are using the `<IMG>` tag:

CSS

```
.container{max-width-500px;}
.container img{width:100%;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="YOUR-IMG-URL" />
</div>
```